# I have two buttons when i click on plus button the web page has to zoom in and click on minus button to zoom out .click on other button to default

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var currFFZoom = 1;
var currIEZoom = 100;

$('#plusBtn').on('click',function(){
    if ($.browser.mozilla){
        var step = 0.02;
        currFFZoom += step; 
        $('body').css('MozTransform','scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');
    } else {
        var step = 2;
        currIEZoom += step;
        $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
    }
});

$('#minusBtn').on('click',function(){
    if ($.browser.mozilla){
        var step = 0.02;
        currFFZoom -= step;                 
        $('body').css('MozTransform','scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');

    } else {
        var step = 2;
        currIEZoom -= step;
        $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
    }
});
```

I have used this code in `Javascript`, it is not working. Can i get any ideas regarding this requirement ?

I have two buttons when I click on plus button the web page has to zoom in and a click on minus button to zoom out and a click on other button to default.

Comment: Did you use Firefox or IE to view your page?

Comment: all chrome firefox and ie

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: now it is working fine but there are when we click zoom in and zoom out again it is automatic reloading into the original size

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your code slightly to correct a couple of things. The `MozTransform` CSS property should be `-moz-transform` instead. I have also removed a couple of unnecessary spaces you were adding to the property value:

```
var currFFZoom = 1;
var currIEZoom = 100;

$('#plusBtn').on('click',function(){
    if ($.browser.mozilla){
        var step = 0.02;
        currFFZoom += step; 
        $('body').css('-moz-transform', 'scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');
    } else {
        var step = 2;
        currIEZoom += step;
        $('body').css('zoom', currIEZoom + '%');
    }
});

$('#minusBtn').on('click',function(){
    if ($.browser.mozilla){
        var step = 0.02;
        currFFZoom -= step;                 
        $('body').css('-moz-transform', 'scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');

    } else {
        var step = 2;
        currIEZoom -= step;
        $('body').css('zoom', currIEZoom + '%');
    }
});
```

See it here working: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Bc3V/1/).

### Edit 1

I had left some alerts in the code but just removed them.
Also explained the changes I did in your code.

### Edit 2

Beware that `$.browser` is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) and should be used with care or alternatively replaced with [Feature & Browser Detection](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/feature-browser-detection/).

Comment: now it is working fine but there are when we click zoom in and zoom out again it is automatic reloading into the original size

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to say. Are you trying to say that when you click zoom-in ("100%" to "102%") and then zoom-out (102% to 100%) it will return to the original size? I guess this is normal. Or are you saying that when you click the zoom-in it increases and goes immediately back to 100%?